# What is the order of the group?

Tags: finite-groups, gap

I am trying to calculate the order of the subgroup of the group of unitary matrices generated by the matrices $$
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\     1 & -1 \      \end{array} } \right]
, 
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\      0 & i \      \end{array} } \right]
.$$ I know so far that should be a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 4):

The group has order 192 (which was obtained using GAP:

```
gap> M1:=[[1,1],[1,-1]]*1/ER(2);;
gap> M2:=[[1,0],[0,E(4)]];;
gap> g:=Group(M1,M2);;
gap> Size(g);
192
```

I'm not sure how to prove this by hand without going into substantial boring arithmetic: The representation is irreducible (otherwise the group would be abelian). Most "obvious" vectors have an orbit length of 48.

Somewhat cheating (as I got this with the computer as well), you could verify that the group satisfies the following relators
$$F_1^2,\qquad F_2^4,\qquad F_2^{-1}(F_1F_2)^3(F_1F_2^{-1})^2F_1,\qquad (F_2^{-1}F_1F_2F_1)^6
$$
and use these to show its order is at most 192.

Comment: :can GAP help to figure the finite subgroup with constraint like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728576/expression-of-unitary-group-the-discrete-subgroups-and-invariants ?