# Expression of unitary group , the discrete subgroups and invariants

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, finite-groups, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $$G=U(3),$$ be the unitary group. Here we consider $G$ in terms of the fundamental representation of U(3). Namely, all of $g \in G$ can be written as a rank-3 (3 by 3) matrices.

1. What is the convenient way to parametrize the rank-3 matrix in terms of a 9 degrees of freedom (for 9 generators)?
2. Can we find some subgroup of Lie group,  $$k \in K \subset G= U(3) $$  such that

   > $$ 
   > k^T \{R_1, R_2\} k =\{R_1, R_2\} .
   > $$
   >   This means that set $\{R_1, R_2\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$. Namely, both cases are allowed:
   >   $$ 
   > k^T R_1  k =R_1,\;\;\;  k^T R_2 k =R_2 .
   > $$
   >   $$ 
   > k^T R_1  k =R_2,\;\;\; k^T R_1 k =R_2 .
   > $$

Here $k^T$ is the transpose of $k$.
What is the full subset (or subgroup) of $K$?

Here we define: 
$$
R_1 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;\;\; R_2 =-R_1=
-\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

This means that $k^T R_a k=R_b$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$, where $a,b \in \{1,2 \}$. But overall the full set $ \{R_1, R_2\}$ is invariant under the transformation by $k$.

There must be a trivial element $k=$ the rank-3 identity matrix. But what else can it allow? In particular, I can see an SU(2) and an additional $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ structure in $K$.

> How could we determine the complete $K$?

Edit: More clarifications. Simplified the problem.

Comment: (1) For what purpose? I like to think of $U(n)$ as exactly the linear operators that act diagonally by unit complex scalars in orthogonal bases. (2) If $K$ is a connected subgroup acting on the discrete set $\{R_1,R_2,R_3\}$, then it must act trivially (so each $R_i$ is indeed fixed) which leaves only $K=Z(U(3))$ the group of unitary scalar matrices.

Comment: @ anon, however the $K$ may be discrete in $U(3)$. This is the subtle part of this question.

Comment: @ anon, thanks for the comment, but one needs to consider the finite part too.

Comment: Is there any reason why you chose the transpose of $k$, not the conjugate transpose of $k$?

Comment: Because it is my choice of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question.** Let $R_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Find the subgroup $K$ of $U(3)$, where
>   $$
> K=\{k\in U(3)\mid k^TR_1k=R_1\text{ or }-R_1\}
> $$
>
> **Answer.** Denote by $SU(2)\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ the group of $2\times2$ unitary matrices with determinant $\pm1$. Then
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> K &= \Bigl\{ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \mp\bar\beta & 0 \\ \beta & \pm\bar\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{pmatrix} \in U(3) \mid \alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C},\,|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=|\gamma|=1 \Bigr\} \\
> &\cong (SU(2)\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2)\times U(1)
> \end{align*}
> $$

**Solution.** Let us find $k=(k_{ij})$ such that $k^TR_1k=R_1$ or $-R_1$. It implies the following three equations
$$
k_{11}k_{23} = k_{13}k_{21}, \quad
k_{12}k_{23} = k_{13}k_{22}, \quad
k_{11}k_{22} - k_{12}k_{21} = \pm1 \tag{*}
$$

> **Claim 1.** $k_{13}=0$ and $k_{23}=0$.
>
> *Proof.* If $k_{13}\neq 0$, then by the Gaussian elimination
>   $$
> k=\begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} & k_{13} \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & k_{23} \\ k_{31} & k_{32} & k_{33} \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} & k_{13} \\ k_{21}-k_{11}(\frac{k_{23}}{k_{13}}) & k_{22}-k_{12}(\frac{k_{23}}{k_{13}}) & k_{23}-k_{13}(\frac{k_{23}}{k_{13}}) \\ k_{31} & k_{32} & k_{33} \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} & k_{13} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ k_{31} & k_{32} & k_{33} \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   $k$ is singular which contradicts to $k\in U(3)$. In the same way, we can prove that $k_{23}=0$ too.

Now the three equations in (*) are reduced to only one equation
$$
k_{11}k_{22} - k_{12}k_{21} = \begin{cases} +1 & \text{if $k^TR_1k=R_1$} \\ -1 & \text{if $k^TR_1k=-R_1$} \end{cases} \tag{**}
$$

> **Claim 2.** $k_{31}=k_{32}=0$.
>
> *Proof.* Since $k\in U(3)$,
>   $$
> k^\dagger k=\begin{pmatrix} * & * & \bar k_{31} \\ * & * & \bar k_{32} \\ 0 & 0 & \bar k_{33} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} * & * & 0 \\ * & * & 0 \\ k_{31} & k_{32} & k_{33} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} * & * & * \\ * & * & * \\ k_{31}\bar k_{33} & k_{32}\bar k_{33} & k_{33}\bar k_{33} \end{pmatrix} = I
> $$
>   where $k^\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $k$.
>   From $k_{33}\bar k_{33}=|k_{33}|^2=1$, we have $\bar k_{33}\neq0$ so that $k_{31}=k_{32}=0$.

Now we have $k=\begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} & 0 \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & k_{33} \end{pmatrix}\in U(2)\times U(1)$ where $|k_{33}|=1$, and the equation (**) implies that the determinant of the sub-matrix $\begin{pmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} \\ k_{21} & k_{22} \end{pmatrix}\in U(2)$ is $\pm1$.

On the contrary, it is easy to check this form of $k$ satisfies $k^TR_1k=R_1$ or $-R_1$.

**Note.** For the first question, I do not know any convenient way to parametrize $U(3)$.

Comment: Thanks  +1. What is the full group? I find it has at least something like (SU(2) $\times \mathbb{Z}_2$) $\rtimes  \mathbb{Z}_2$, but one needs to make precise all the definitions of groups and semi direction extension etc to get a precise accepted answer. :-)

Comment: @annieheart The set of unitary matrices having determinant $\pm1$ can be seen as $SU(2)\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$. I modified my answer using the semidirect product notation. Thanks.

Comment: @ ChoF, if it is really correct, I will accept it. Just to make sure, (1) here we set $G=$U(3), but if we have $G=$SU(3) instead, what will be your answer? Just to see the consistency

Comment: @ annie heart, in that case of $G=SU(3)$, I think $(SU(2)\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Comment: @annieheart Please read my answer and the proof. It's simple. If $G$ is special unitary, the answer is of course $SU(2)\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$ as wonderich said. Thanks wonderich. Notice $\gamma=\pm1$ changes according to the determinant of $U(2)$ matrix.

Comment: @ Choi, indeed I may agree with your answer. I will accept it in a few days if there is no better answer. Thanks

Comment: @ Choi, may I make sure that the imaginary $\pm i$ times a 3 by 3 diagonal identity matrix is also part of your solution? But it is not generated by the U(1) parametrized by your $\gamma$ alone. Where can we find this  $\pm i \mathbb{I}$ in your solution? (or do you miss it?)

Comment: @annieheart Both the diagonal matrices $\pm i$ times the identity matrix are included in the solution set, since the determinant of the $U(2)$ part is $-1$ and the imaginary $\lambda=i$ is included in $U(1)$, which is nothing but the set of $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$. Of course $|i|=1$. P.S. My name is CHO not CHOI.

Comment: Thanks ChoF. [It was due to the computer automatic spelling correction, please pardon me]